# SSIS Loopeach file variable not maintained

Tags: loops, variables, ssis

I have done a couple projects using the LoopEach construct.  This the first where I'm generating an output file inside a Data Flow in the loop.

I have a script that extracts the path and basename of the input file.  I have looked at that is extracted (using FileInfo) and it is correct.

A few steps later, I am outputing to a flat file.  I have both the input and output connection managers set to DelayValidation.  The output keeps failing. Although I have the output set to a variable that includes the input file name (so it will continue to change, the output fails and shows the filename without the info from the variable.

The variable is set to a scope of the package, so it should be covered.

What am I missing???

Comment: BTW, I have the connection manager Expression set with the the variable.  It is a compound variable and constant.

Comment: @[User::RelPathName] +  @[User::RelBaseName] + "." +  @[$Package::DupRelFile] + ".txt"

Comment: @[User::RelPathName] +  @[User::RelBaseName] + "." +  @[$Package::DupRelFile] + ".txt". where the different variables have been checked.  at this point, I am only going through a SINGLE file, which makes this even more confusing.

Comment: If you check the value of the variable right before your output step, does that reveal anything?

Comment: Chris, That's part of what I don't understand.  I replace the file destination with a script just so I can see the variables...and they are empty.  One thing I meant to add is that while the script pulling apart the input file name into basename and path, I can still see the components.  While things normally stop on a breakpoint and the remaining parts are waiting, in this case the flow continues. Thus, while I have the breakpoint set and the c# code opens, I can see that it has reached the point where the output would be.

Comment: Do your variables contain values at any point? When do they become empty?

Comment: I can see that the variables are loaded two steps before in the same Dataflow.  yet, they show empty just two steps later.  It's very odd.  As I mentioned, what seems to occur is that the dataflow seems to operate asynchronously.  as someone that used to do real-time development, I can see a timing issue where while the variables are loaded, the later steps actually happens before this is completed.

Comment: I reread your question. What is the actual error message you are getting when you try to output the flat file?

Comment: I get a message that the file cannot be opened.  It shows the filename without the path; only part of the complete name.  For example, if I have the input file of "c:\abc\input\newfile.txt" and the expression is to take the path ("c:\abc\), the basename ("newfile.txt"), and also apply a fixed token ("errorfile") so the final should be "c:\abc\newfile.txt.errorfile", the message only shows "errorfile".  Even then, the output should be somewhere, but it might be applying this to a local drive on the server, which I don't have rights to...thus, the error makes sense.

Comment: What does not is that I can set a breakpoint in the script that is pulling the path and basename (out of FileInfo), it is putting it into a variable for the project (so it is available throughout the operation), yet the last stage shows nothing in the path nor basename.  As I mentioned, it acts as if it is working asynchronously to the front script and the variable is not ready at the point the later stage is operating.  Nor sure how to force this action.  I will try tomorrow to create a second dataflow to operate this side, but this should NOT be necessary (I would think).

Comment: Could you post screenshots? I'm not sure what you mean by asynchronous, should this be taken care of by precedence constraints?

Comment: I fixed it, though I don't see why.  the issue WAS that the end of the dataflow was running BEFORE the variable was set.  I moved the setting of the variable OUTSIDE the dataflow but inside the Foreach loop.  Now there is a constraint before the dataflow runs so the variables are forced to be set.  Odd, but something new learned. :)

Comment: Glad to hear it! :)